# Matplotlib difference between two images

Tags: matplotlib, plot, patch, figure

I have images (4000x2000 pixels) that are derived from the same image, but with subtle differences in less than 1% of the pixels. I'd like to plot the two images side-by-side and **highlight** the regions of the array's that are different (by **highlight** I mean I want the pixels that differ to jump out, but **still display the color that matches their value**. I've been using rectangles that are unfilled to outline the edges of such pixels so far. I can do this very nicely in small images (~50x50) with:

```
    fig=figure(figsize=(20,15))
    ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
    imshow(image1,interpolation='nearest',origin='lower left')
    colorbar()
    ax2=fig.add_subplot(122,sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
    imshow(image2,interpolation='nearest',origin='lower left')
    colorbar()
    #now show differences
    Xspots=im1!=im2
    Xx,Xy=nonzero(Xspots)
    for x,y in zip(Xx,Xy):
           rect=Rectangle((y-.5,x-.5),1,1,color='w',fill=False,ec='w')
           ax1.add_patch(rect)
           ax2.add_patch(rect)
```

However this doesn't work so well when the image is very large. Strange things happen, for example when I zoom in the patch disappears. Also, this way sucks because it takes forever to load things when I zoom in/out.

I feel like there must be a better way to do this, maybe one where there is only one patch that determines where all of the things are, rather than a whole bunch of patches. I could do a scatter plot on top of the imshow image, but I don't know how to fix it so that the points will stay exactly the size of the pixel when I zoom in/out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something with the alpha channel:

```
import copy
N, M = 20, 40
test_data = np.random.rand(N, M)
mark_mask = np.random.rand(N, M) < .01 # mask 1%
# this is redundant in this case, but in general you need it
my_norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
# grab a copy of the color map
my_cmap = copy.copy(cm.get_cmap('cubehelix'))
c_data= my_cmap(my_norm(test_data))
c_data[:, :, 3] = .5 # make everything half alpha
c_data[mark_mask, 3] = 1 # reset the marked pixels as full opacity
# plot it
figure()
imshow(c_data, interpolation='none')
```

No idea if this will work with your data or not.

Comment: This, again, works for small images (with sizes~20x40), but won't work for larger images (with sizes above ~1000x1000). It leaves me with a background that is greyed out, and even when I zoom in to a small sized image from a larger image, the background still looks grey rather than a .5 alpha version of what it's supposed to look like. Any other ideas?

Comment: It works fine for me when you zoom in.  What color map are you using?

Comment: Actually now that I'm trying it on a computer with a faster processor/better graphics card it actually looks pretty good. Thanks!